# Dynatable js show modal after select val

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, dynatable

I use dynatable and i have in my row a select when the val =5 a modal window show, but when i change paage or use seaarch input my modal don't show when the select value is at 5.

Thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Srry after reflexion if i forgot to shwo id of my value in my modal box